# How to see non Instrumented Elements on iOS app

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, appium-ios

I'm trying to run an automation script for an iOS app. I'm using "instrument" method. But, sometimes there are some field not seen with these method and only seen with non-instrument method. How can I read the non_instrument field in a code that only can read instrument field please ?

I used the parameter `nixpath` for the non_instrument field but this parameter is not seen by eclipse.

```
@Test (description="Login with wrong username and password")
@Parameters({ "Username_KO" , "Password_KO" })
public void login_fail1(String Username_KO, String Password_KO) throws Exception {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='UIView' and ./*[@text='' and ./*[@text='Username']]]"))
          .sendKeys(Username_KO);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='_UIButtonBarButton']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_UIButtonBarButton']"))
          .click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='UIView' and ./*[@text and ./*[@accessibilityLabel='Password']] and ./*[@class='UIImageView']]"))
          .sendKeys(Password_KO);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_UIButtonBarButton']"))
          .click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@accessibilityLabel='Sign In' and @class='FMS.Button']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@accessibilityLabel='Sign In' and @class='FMS.Button']"))
          .click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='FMS' and @class='UIAStaticText']")));
    driver.findElement(By.niXpath("//*[@text='FMS' and @class='UIAStaticText']"))
          .click();           
    driver.findElement(By.nixpath("//*[@text='Wrong username or password. Please try again']"));
    driver.findElement(By.nixpath("//*[@text='Ok']"))
          .click();

}
```

Comment: What is an `instrument` method? What is a `non_instrument field`? I have no idea what this is about

Comment: on iOS, we have two method to see xpath of field. The normal one named non_instrument method and the other named "instrument method". The utility of the last is to give the xpath of the fields not seen in the first method